# Throwing an ender pearl at a slime block while falling

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried throwing an ender pearl at a slime block and I noticed that the amount I bounce depends on how fast I'm falling when the ender pearl hits (I think, it's a somewhat difficult experiment to set up correctly).  Can someone else confirm this?

Comment: in other word is the relevant momentum maintained when throwing an enderpearl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the 1.8 snapshots, velocity is indeed maintained between teleports.  [Minecraft Wiki Reference (scroll down a bit)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/14w02a#Changes)